# padding not working in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I know this is very small issue but i can't determine this.

i write css style `padding: 1em` and it's works fine for chrome and firefox. But in IE it's not working.

Why this not work with IE9

**See screenshot**.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

```css
.thumbnail-menu-image img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.thumbnail-menu-caption {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-menu-image">
  <img src="https://www.gettyimages.fi/landing/assets/static_content/home/info-tabs3.jpg" width="440" height="250" alt="">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-menu-caption">
  <h3 class="thumbnail-menu-caption-title">Umzugsangebot</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a complete code snippet for this, so that we can see what might cause that behaviour ?

Comment: And which IE are you talking about?

Comment: 1/ Do you really have visits from IE9 in your logs? The OS it could run with isn't supported by MS anymore so it's risky... But I don't know for India so just asking :) 2/ Are you trying with a real IE9 (modern.ie to the rescue), not some other version with emulation? 3/ Re: your question ⇒ Did you try `img { vertical-align: top; }` (you already have `display: block`, fine. Maybe try with inline-block…